# Word that mean "to hold" but something that you're already holding?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Example:

> "I'm not in the mood for jokes," she said, [...] her fork and looking
> at her plate again.

So in the example, the person was already holding the fork.

The two words that come to my mind are *grip* and *clutch*. I'm not sure, though, if they imply *taking* the thing first:

> **grip** 
> take and keep a firm hold of; grasp tightly.
>
> **clutch** 
> grasp (something) tightly.
>
> **grasp** 
> seize and hold firmly.

Source: [Google](http://google.com/).

Is there a better word? Or I can use one of the options above? (Maybe one of the doesn't imply to *take* or *seize* so much?)

Comment: Depends on what you want to convey.  *grip* and *clutch* when used of a fork both suggest a rather indelicate use of the hand. Old cowpokes out on the range, eating a plate of beans beside a campfire, clutch their forks. (See also http://victualling.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/manwnapkin15.jpg)

Comment: ["gripping her fork"](https://www.google.it/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22gripping+her%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22gripping+her+fork%22) would do just as well. See Google books results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to convey the idea that she is in a bad mood and that during the conversation she has become more tensed (and as a result of this she has strengthened her grip on her fork), perhaps you can say:

> "I'm not in the mood for jokes," she said, ***tightening her grip*** on her fork and looking at her plate again.

Answer (score 5):

Not convinced of what you want to convey, I proffer-

[tweak](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/tweak):

1. adjust finely, 2. *pull or pull out sharply*

[twinge](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/twinge):

*squeeze tightly between the fingers*

> I'm not in the mood for jokes," she said, [*tweaking*] her fork and
>   looking at her plate again.

([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/tweak))

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convey the meaning of a very **firm** hold on the fork, your first two choices are fine and don't necessarily connote taking into one's hand before holding (as Tim Romano pointed out in his comment). I would say that *clutch* has a slightly more "not implying taking first" feel than grip:

**[clutch](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/clutch_1)** (LDOCE):

> clutch
>   1 [transitive]
>
> to hold something tightly because you do not want to lose it

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clutch):

> to hold onto (someone or something) tightly with your hand

There are other definitions in these dictionaries, where *to clutch* also includes taking hold of, but the fact that there is a definition without this meaning says (to me at least) that the word can be used without this "to take first" connotation. Same goes for:

**[to grip](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/grip_2)** (LDOCE):

> [transitive]
>
> to hold something very tightly:

I haven't found evidence that same applies to *grasp*.

---

If you don't want to say that the hold was firm, then a present participle form of your very own *to hold* would work:

> "I'm not in the mood for jokes," she said, (still) **holding** her fork and looking at her plate again.

Or if you would allow slight rephrasing:

> - "I'm not in the mood for jokes," she said, looking at her plate again while holding her fork.
> - "I'm not in the mood for jokes," she said, with a fork in her hand, looking at her plate again.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe [wield](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wield) could fit your need

> Hold and use (a weapon or tool)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find the word for continuing to hold something, I believe the word "hold" is already sufficient. From [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold), the definition of hold:

> : to have or keep (something) in your hand, arms, etc.
>
> : to put your arms around (someone) : to embrace or hug (someone)
>
> : to put or keep (something or someone) in a specified place or position

As you can see, part of the definition is to keep it in one's grasp.